# Access making a report on update/creation of a data

Tags: ms-access

i am trying to create a Report based on a query which will be made on each 
creation / update of my DataBase
i attach the report to a button with a macro, 
problem is that if nothing was changed and someone just press over the button the report would be fired but with no data, and if the data was inserted to the text boxes and i press over the button with the macro the data does not append to the data base.

my macro lines:

```
OnError    Next,
OpenReport Accept, Report, , , Normal // Accept is the name of the report
GoToRecord Next,
[MacroError]<>0 =[MacroError].[Description], Yes, None,
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to test and track this would be by adding a 'Yes/No' field called for example "flgReported" in to one of the tables used in the query, then after running your report you could update all rows to true. Any new rows added afterwards would then be false and you could bring this in to your select query to only report on False rows, this would also allow you to test whether there was any data to return when clicking the button before going ahead and running the report.

Update: If you highlight the macro in question and then goto "Tools > Macro > Convert Macro's to Visual Basic" and then click 'Convert' it will generate the VB code for you.  This could then be called from your button instead of the Macro and before the main procedure you could insert this to check if there were any new records:

```
Private Sub ButtonClick() "For Example"

Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM queryname where flgReported = False")

    If rs.BOF And rs.EOF then 'No Records to report so we quit at this point
        rs.close
        set rs = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Remainder of Macro Code goes here

    'Then run a simple SQL here to update the flags to True

End Sub
```

Comment: indeed not a bad way but i have no clue how to write VB code to check this , the SQL code for this would be easy ofc

Comment: @NadavStern I've updated my answer with some sample code that will hopefully help